# Whats wrong with my backgroundwork method

Tags: wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am trying to get a background worker process working in a wpf application. it creates 2 files then crashes.

```
   BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
                        {
                            CreateFile(i.ToString());
                        };
                        worker.RunWorkerAsync();


private void CreateFile(string fileName)
    {
        string path = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}.txt", directory, fileName);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(fileName);
        }
    }
```

I get this error "
The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open." what am I doing wrong?

Any help would be great

Comment: Serious answer?  Pretty much everything.

Comment: What is 'i'?  What your showing will only create 1 file.  Do you have multiple calls to RunWorkerAsync()?  Can you explain more of what you're trying to do?

Comment: 1. What are you trying to achieve at the big-picture level? I'm missing some context - as in how are 2 files being created / the value of the dir variable.. more code would be welcome.
2. Can you try and identify the filepath when the crash occurs and use ProcExp to see which processes are holding handles to it at the point of crash?

Comment: Hi there,

Sorry yes this is a short version of the my code. I basically have a for loop that I have the background worker code inside.

I was using the loop to create the new file using CreateFile


It is a simply example I have but I just want to get an understanding how it works.



Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another process has the file open, e.g., an antivirus program or WordPad. You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which process it is.